# Is $g(y)=\min_{x\in E} f(x,y)$ continuous

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, maxima-minima, supremum-and-infimum

Suppose $f:R^{n}\times R^{m}\rightarrow R$ is continuous, and $E\subset R^{n}$ is closed and bounded. Is $$g(y)=\min_{x \in E} f(x,y)$$ continuous?

If not, on what conditions will $g$ become continuous?

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

The set-valued function $\Gamma(y) = E$ for all $y \in R^n$ is compact-valued, upper semi-continuous and lower semi-continuous. Thus, we can apply the [Berge maximum theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_theorem) to conclude that $g$ is a continuous function. We can even say more. Let $\Gamma^*(y)$ denote the set of solutions $x^*$ such that $f(x^*,y) = g(y)$. Then $\Gamma^*(y)$ is compact-valued and upper semi-continuous.